# TypeError : a byte-like object is required , not 'str'

Tags: python, python-xmlschema

I have a scenario where book id wise i am creating separate file and reading all files and inserting it into one file
How to write all file data to one file ?

**Where all data will be line by line in one file**

book 1 | author | genere | price | publish_date | description

book 2 | author | genere | price | publish_date | description

Note : data should be in pipe separated format `'|'`

**xml data :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

**I tried code :**

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ET.ElementTree(file='/d/demo.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for books in root:
    if(books.tag=='book'):
       f=open(book.get(id) + '.txt' ,'wb')
         for attr in books:
             if (attr.tag='author' or attr.tag='title' or attr.tag='price' or attr.tag='genre' or attr.tag='publish_date' or attr.tag='description')
                 f.write(attr.tag + ':' + attr.text)
```

**Required output in below format :**

```
Gambardella , Matthew |XML Developer's Guide | Computer | 44.95 | 2000-10-01 | An in-depth look at creating applications with XML
Ralls, Kim | Midnight Rain | Fantasy | 5.95 | 2000-12-16 | A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.
```

Comment: culd you post the entire stack trace? what line is giving the error?

also your second if statements needs more "="'s

Comment: @BendikKnapstad  I am learning from you tube and practising : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZY_dcIVEooU&t=780s   here he got all data into separate file but i want data into one file that too in pipe separated format

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the output as a binary file - if you do so, you can only write `bytes` to it. Open it as a normal text file and specify an encoding. Also, use a `with` statement so you don't need to close the file manually and are safe in case of errors:

```
with open(book.get(id) '.txt' ,'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     for attr in books:
         if (attr.tag='author' or attr.tag='title' or attr.tag='price' or attr.tag='genre' or attr.tag='publish_date' or attr.tag='description')
             f.write(attr.tag + ':' + attr.text)
```

Comment: can you consolidate data into one file as shown in question above , required data in pipe separated format